# How to apply these filters

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, filters

I bought woocommerce compare plugin. Unfortunately I can't understand how to apply some filters.

For example I want to increase compare limit tom 10. How ı can use below filte?

apply_filters( ‘woocommerce_products_compare_max_products’, int ) – sets how many products can be compared at one time. Default is 5.

What I tried but not working;

```
   function comparelimit($location){
       $location = 10;
    }
    apply_filters( ‘woocommerce_products_compare_max_products’, 'comparelimit');
```

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-products-compare/

Comment: How to use filters is well documented: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/filters/

Comment: Thanks, I have read it. But some how I can't make it work.

Comment: Your best bet would be to check with the plugin developer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to return the value in the function for it to be accessible outside that function

```
function comparelimit( $location ) {
    $location = 10;
    return $location;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_products_compare_max_products', 'comparelimit' );
```

Comment: Actually, I did try this too. But still see error message after 5 product. Tried again now. But still didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Both are working now :)
I don't know what changed.

Here is code for change product-compare page to what ever you want

```
function comparerename()
{
    return 'karsilastir';
}
add_filter('woocommerce_products_compare_end_point' ,'comparerename');
```

here is the code to change compare limit

```
function comparelimit( $location ) {
    $location = 8;
    return $location;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_products_compare_max_products', 'comparelimit' );
```

If anyone can teach me how to use below one, that would be great.

```
apply_filters( ‘woocommerce_products_compare_compare_button’, html ) – filters the display of the compare products button.

apply_filters( ‘woocommerce_products_compare_meta_headers’, array ) – filters the headers displayed on the compare products page.
```

Answer (score -1):

Weirdly this solved my problem.I am not sure if woocommerce's documentation is wrong.

```
    function comparelimit( $location ) {
    $location = 10;
    return $location;
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_products_compare_max_products', 'comparelimit' );
```

Comment: 'woocommerce_products_compare_max_products' is a filter not an action. There is no possible way this could work the way you say it worked.

Comment: Hi Cornel, I agree with you but working. 
Default it 5, as you see here it is 8 now for me. https://prnt.sc/121ecbs

And this is the screenshot from code snippet plugin. https://prnt.sc/121eeio

Do you have any suggestion?